debuginfod.sh: line 9: tr: command not found, root access seems to be struggling, unsure what to repair or how
I have an Ubuntu operating system, the most recent version. I'm brand new to Linux and computer commands in general and I've exhausted my limited ability in trying to figure out what's happening.
Yesterday I uninstalled Lutris using the sudo apt autouninstall command I found through another question on this site. This morning I turned on my PC, and got the following error message.

I did some googling and found that it was likely a coreutils issue . I tried updating and reinstalling it, and got the next image issue.

I followed some instructions that I found here on a different post with seemingly the same issue. The instructions were to boot in recovery mode, go to root access, and type sudo fsck -f/ to check for errors (fsck.ext4: invalid option -- '/'). My recovery menu is a bit of a mess and now I'm totally lost. This is what is currently on my screen.

Is it better to cut my losses and install a new version of Ubuntu, or is this somehow solvable?

If you deleted the tr program, then a simple apt install won't restore it - you'd need sudo apt reinstall coreutils

may be defeatist but if you have little or no experience of Ubuntu it may be sensible to start over and then follow this guide

Please be specific with details; you do mention you're using the most recent version, but then your picture shows an older version of coreutils and not coreutils | 9.4-3.1ubuntu1      | oracular which is the October 2024 or most recent version.  Your picture does NOT match your description, and its hard to give advice when what we're provided is incorrect.  Its best to avoid latest or recent if you're not familiar enough with the system to know what exists (I gather you're using the 2024-April release or 24.04 & not the newer 2024-October or 24.10 release; are you??)

sudo fsck -f/ returned a fsck.ext4: invalid option -- '/' error message because the command was wrong. The correct command should be sudo fsck -f / with a space character separating the f from the /. What happens when you run the correct command from an Ubuntu live USB? Since the root filesystem (/) is usually mounted and in use when the system is running, you cannot safely perform a full check or repair on it while the system is active. Running fsck on a mounted filesystem can lead to serious corruption.

The command sudo apt autouninstall does not exist in Ubuntu's apt package manager, so running it will output an E: Invalid operation autouninstall error.
